# Javascript code not being executed on button click

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have some html and some javascript code that is supposed to take input in a text box, and open a new tab with the Wikipedia page of whatever was in the text box. However, I'm using this as an extension, and google chrome doesn't allow inline javascript.
page.js

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", searchPage);

function searchPage() {
    console.log("test")
    var temp = document.getElementById(pageName);
    var temp = temp.value;
    var myPage = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + temp;
    window.location.replace(myPage);
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/" target="_blank">Random</a>
        Enter page to lookup: <input type="text" id="pageName" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="search" />
        <script src="./page.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any clue why this isn't working?

Comment: I think you mean `document.getElementById("pageName")`.

Comment: Changed, nothing happened. I still get no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do instead is include your JS in your HTML `<head>` tag, and add an `onClick` attribute to your button, like so:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/" target="_blank">$
        Enter page to lookup: <input type="text" id="pageName" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="search" />
        <script src="./page.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think the problem was that in your original code, you had `<script src="./page.js></script>` instead of `<script src="./page.js"></script>`

then you can change your javascript to be the following:

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', searchPage);

function searchPage() {
    console.log("hjabdfs");
    var temp = document.getElementById('pageName');
    var temp = temp.value;
    var myPage = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + temp;
    window.location.replace(myPage);
}
```

please note that I also changed `var temp = document.getElementById(pageName)` to `var temp = document.getElementById('pageName')`, as `pageName` is not a variable.

Comment: Chrome extensions won't work and will throw errors when scripts use "onclick" or are included in a head tag.

Comment: apologies - please check the revision. hopefully this works :)

Comment: Great! I get console output from the `console.log()`, but no new page opens. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: in my browser, what happens is the search is opened in the current tab, but a new tab is opened with the "Random" wikipedia page. this is because your `<a>` tag isn't closed. to fix this, you should put 

`<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/" target="_blank">$Enter page to lookup: </a> <input type="text" id="pageName" /><br />`

(notice the closing tag at the end)

Comment: It's closed, I just forget that nano likes to end lines that are too big for the screen with `$`the actual code is `<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/" target="_blank">Random</a>`

Comment: oh, yeah. nano is annoying like that. what exactly is happening in your browser, then? you may not be being directed to a new page because you're not actually opening a new tab -- what you're doing is trying to make the current tab go to the wiki page, which may not be possible in the Chrome popup.

Comment: Absolutely NOTHING is happening in my browser. When I click "Inspect popup", and click the button, I get the output from `console.log()`, but that's it. I tried changing `window.location.replace` to `window.location.href`, but it throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`

Comment: try `window.open(myPage, '_blank');` instead of `window.location.replace(myPage);`

Answer (score 0):

Input type submit is trying to submit a form. You need to add an action to that submit button or you can change it to a button and the event will fire.

Comment: I changed the type to "button", but I still get nothing. Would I have to change "value" as well?

Comment: <button type="button" id="search" >Search!</button> also side note, in your search function you are defining temp twice, only define the variable once

Comment: The script isn't being executed at all. I tried moving it to the top of the body, but I get an "Uncaught TyepError"

Comment: I moved the script to the top of the body tag after the edits, but now the link, button, text, and text box have completely disappeared

Comment: Sounds like the script is running then. You also are missing a semi colon on your console.log that could be causing the issue

Comment: COMPLETELY missed that. Hard to switch to javascript from python. Script still isn't giving any output to the console, or opening the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your `click` event listener doesn't work because it has not been loaded yet. Or in other words, you need to make sure this line `<script src="./page.js></script>` is correctly pointing to `page.js`.